# Allow sessions on multiple domains with www and without www

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config

I have multiple domains pointing to one Web application. Here are a few, just as an examples, so that I can reference them in my examples.

- `www.mydomain.com`
- `sub.mydomain.com`
- `www.affiliatedomain.com`

ASP.NET allows for a web.config setting to accomplish this:

`<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" domain=".mydomain.com" />`

This allows me to share sessions between the `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` domains. Perfect! Except it only works for one domain.

Another avenue I explored was url rewriting. I could insert a rewrite rule to ensure that only `www` urls are being accessed but doing so (at least the one I write) works for the domains, but appends a `www.` to the `sub.mydomain.com` resulting in a failed `www.sub.mydomain.com` - which won't work. Perhaps this option could still work if someone knows how to formulate url rewrite urls better than me.

Finally, to be clear, I don't need to share sessions across all domains (I know this is not possible). I just would like to share domains across the same domain with and without `www`.

For example: `www.mydomain.com` *and* `mydomain.com`

Or `www.affiliatedomain.com` and `affiliatedomain.com`

The `sub.mydomain.com` can live on its own so long as it never has a `www.` in front of it.

Comment: Cookies aren't supposed to be shared across "top level" domains, so what you're seeing is correct.

Comment: @TiesonT. - I'm not trying to share cookies across top level domains. Just between the same domain with www and without www.,

Comment: Since you have multiple domains pointing to the same instance, it more or less _is_ what you're trying to do. If keeping a user authenticated from one domain to the other isn't a goal, you *might* be able to set the domain on the session/cookie when a user signs in (OWIN actually makes this easier than it used to be).

Comment: @TiesonT. - This is a complicated issue so I'm probably not communicating it very accurately. I need to be clear here that the only session sharing I want to do is between domains that have and do not have the www subdomain. I don't need to share between `x1.com` and `x2.com` - but I do need to share between `www.x1.com` and `x1.com` - Reread my original post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think the rewrite option is best for your case, something like this should fix the sub domain rewrite issue.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. Even if it did, your Redirect wouldn't account for the other possible affiliatedomain.com, not just mydomain.com